# JavaFX and Gradle: What is the correct way to load a default view?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, javafx

I keep getting "Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0."

I've looked and tried a dozen fixes and tutorials all with the same error. I've moved the view to the every folder and renamed it incase underscores aren't allowed. I've tried every permutation of "/path/file.fxml" I can think of

I have a feeling my code is depreciated but all I can do is get intellij to highlight .load()

Here is my code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ScoreSheet extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new 
FXMLLoader(ScoreSheet.class.getResource("views/main_menu.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Score Sheet");
    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 405, 720);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    }
}
```

Here is my stacktrace:

```
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51285', transport: 'socket'
Gradle Daemon started in 616 ms

> Configure project :
Found module name 'ScoreSheetTest.main'
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51285', transport: 'socket'

> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :jar UP-TO-DATE
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:51290', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:51290', transport: 'socket'
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51285', transport: 'socket'

> Task :ScoreSheet.main() FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
3 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 2 up-to-date
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2541)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2516)
    at ScoreSheetTest.main/com.company.scoresheet.ScoreSheet.start(ScoreSheet.java:16)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':ScoreSheet.main()'.
> Process 'command '/Users/username/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-17.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1


BUILD FAILED in 4s
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51285', transport: 'socket'
2:05:57 PM: Execution finished ':ScoreSheet.main()'.
```

Edit: File structure image [image: File Structure Image]

Edit 2: Here is my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
}

group 'com.iharptech'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
    implementation 'org.openjfx:javafx-controls:18'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs = ["src/main/java"]
            includes = ["**/*.fxml"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The "_Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0._" is almost certainly unrelated to the `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.` error you're getting. The duplicate is for the exception.

Comment: If you want to know which deprecated features of Gradle were used, then you can do what the warning tells you and run Gradle with `--warning-mode all`. If any of the features were used by your own build script, then you can look up what the replacements are and fix the problem. However, if the features were used by a plugin, then really your only options are to make sure you're using the latest version of the plugin or, if you already are using the latest version, submit a bug report with the plugin authors (assuming none exist). Or you could use a different plugin (if possible).

Comment: Okay, but why is the location not set with any of the ways I can put /ScoreSheetTest/src/main/resources/views/main_menu.fxml? I've tried cutting it at each "/" down to just "main_menu.fxml

Comment: The duplicate gives a lot of information about how resource lookup works and ways to debug problems. Try those debugging techniques to see if one solves your problem.

Comment: But with your comment, the path that _should_ work is `.getResource("/views/main_menu.fxml")`.

Comment: Do you know where to add --warning-mode all into intellij to get it to give my any information? I've tried in the Run config under program arugments, environmental variables, and in prefs > Build, Execute, Deploy > Compiler > Java compiler

Comment: Could it be the "Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 405, 720);"?

Comment: No. The "Location is not set" error means, in your case, that `getResource` is returning `null`. And that means the resource could not be found using the specified path. So while the error is only _thrown_ when you call `load()`, the real problem is about 4 lines above that line in your code (i.e., the path you use is wrong, the resource is not being deployed properly, or maybe even something else).

Comment: I'm not sure where you'd set `--warning-mode all` in Intellij, but you could always execute Gradle from the command line (e.g., `./gradlew --warning-mode all run` ← assumes you're using the Gradle wrapper).

Comment: I added an image of the file structure. I also rewrote my call code identical to the duplicate answer, using the URL fxmlResource = getClass().getResource("/views/main_menu.fxml");

Comment: Did you check the build folder/JAR file to make sure the FXML files are being outputted? Also, what is `Execution failed for task ':ScoreSheet.main()'`? More specifically, what is the `ScoreSheet.main()` "task"? Did you create that task your self? Typically the task to run a Java(FX) application is named `run`, and is also typically added by the `application` plugin. Could you add your `gradle.build[.kts]` file to your question?

Comment: I added the build.gradle. I also installed gradle outside of my project so I could launch it in terminal. It says "error: module not found: javafx.controls
    requires javafx.controls;" and error: module not found: javafx.fxml
    requires javafx.fxml;

But I have my javafx-swt in global libraries with all the classes I should need.

Comment: Okay. There seems to be a little confusion regarding how to use Gradle with an IDE (e.g., IntelliJ). I'll reopen your question and try to add a helpful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Gradle Deprecation Warnings

These warnings are almost certainly not related to your `IllegalStateException`.

If you want to know which deprecated features were used, then you can do what the warning message says and use `--warning-mode all`. If the features were used by your own build script, then you can look up the replacements and fix the problem yourself. However, if the features were used by a plugin then really your only options are: (1) Update to use the latest version of the plugin; (2) If already using the latest version, submit a bug report with the plugin authors (if one doesn't already exist); (3) Maybe, if possible, use a different plugin.

---

## Using Gradle with an IDE

When you use a build tool such as Gradle (or e.g., Maven), then you should let the build tool handle all dependencies and other configurations (as much as is possible). In other words, you should be declaring the JavaFX dependencies in your build script, not in IntelliJ.

You should also have the IDE delegate build and run tasks to Gradle. That way Gradle is responsible for everything build related, and the IDE is only responsible for making it easier to write code.

IntelliJ works really well with Gradle. Any dependencies you add to Gradle will be known by IntelliJ. And any tasks supplied by Gradle will also be known by IntelliJ.

### Declare JavaFX Dependencies in Gradle

You're using the OpenJFX [javafx-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-gradle-plugin). That project's README has documentation for how to declare which JavaFX modules you need for your project. **Note the latest version of this plugin is `0.0.12`**. You should update your build script to use that version.

#### Local JavaFX SDK

If you're using a downloaded JavaFX SDK, as your comments seem to imply, then you can use:

```groovy
javafx {
    sdk = '/path/to/sdk' // replace with your own path
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml'] // modify list as needed
}
```

For the `sdk` path, you may want to setup a variable that is then passed by the person who invokes Gradle. That way people on other computers can still build your project without modifying the build script. Though if this is a personal project on a single computer then a static, absolute path should be fine for now.

I don't know when this feature was added to the plugin, so you may **need** to update to the latest version.

#### Maven Central JavaFX JARs

You could instead have Gradle download the needed JavaFX JAR files from Maven Central.

```groovy
javafx {
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml'] // modify list as needed
    version = '18' // change version as needed
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

### Executing Gradle Tasks

You should make run configurations to execute Gradle tasks, rather than letting the IDE use its own build and execution system.

To execute any Gradle task via IntelliJ, you can open up the Gradle tab (typically on the right side of IntelliJ, if I'm not mistaken), select a task, and execute it.

Or you could manually create a "run configuration". Make sure to choose "Gradle" when selecting the type of configuration. Tell it which project the task is for and which task to execute.

#### The Application Plugin

Typically, with JVM projects, when you want to be able to execute your project you should apply the `application` plugin.

```groovy
plugins {
    // other plugins...
    'application'
}
```

You already do this. But you also need to configure the main class and, if present, the main module.

```groovy
application {
    mainModule = '<module-name>'
    mainClass = '<fully-qualified-class-name>'
}
```

The `application` plugin adds the `run` task. To execute your project, have IntelliJ execute the `run` task.

---

## Resources

For general information about resources, how to load them, what paths to use, and some troubleshooting techniques, I recommend this Q&A:

[How do I determine the correct path for FXML files, CSS files, Images, and other resources needed by my JavaFX Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61531317/6395627)

But specifically regarding your setup, you should remove this part from your Gradle build script:

> ```groovy
> sourceSets {
>     main {
>         resources {
>             srcDirs = ["src/main/java"]
>             includes = ["**/*.fxml"]
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

It's not needed. Keeping it means `src/main/resources` is no longer considered a resource root, which you probably do not want.

With that change, and executing the project via the `run` task, using `"/views/main_menu.fxml"` should work for you as the resource path.

Comment: Holy heck. This is a lot to go through. I will pour over it all day Monday, but I can tell you I followed a tutorial that specified using a Zulu package and setting it up in IntelliJ. I have a strong feeling it was missing something Gradle specific that sets up different than maven. Thank you for all your hard work preparing this response.

Comment: Note a lot of what I said applies to Maven as well as Gradle (just Maven uses a `pom.xml` file for configuration, along with some other differences). If you want instructions on setting up JavaFX straight from the "source", check out https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Comment: Okay, I used this information to try three things.

1. I edited my original project files with your suggestions and it works, but it's not using the latest packages.

2. I tried setting up a new "Gradle" project with the IntelliJ wizard. It has problems getting JFX.

3. I set up a new "JavaFX" project using a Gradle build using official repositories instead of manually downloaded ones. I made a few edits to the module-info.java and build.gradle and it just worked after I dumped in my files and renamed the paths.

Thank you so much for all of your help.